# How to render a variable of type HTMLImageElement in Angular 2

Tags: angular

When I do

```ts
<div>my image : {{myVar}}</div>
```

my browser displays

```ts
<div>my image : [object HTMLImageElement]</div>
```

How can I display the image itself instead?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to add an `HTMLImageElement` though Angular bindings.

This should work:

```ts
<div>my image : <span #imgTarget></span></div>
```

```ts
@ViewChild('imgTarget') imgTarget:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.imgTarget.nativeElement.appendChild(this.myVar);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any specific reason why you can't do something like

```
<div>my image : <img src={{image.source}}></div>
```

instead?

Comment: yeah, it could be another dom element type and I want it to be generic

Answer (score 0):

Replace src by attr.src. Try this

my image : img attr.src={{image.source}}>